# Dictionary appears correctly on console.log() but when I try to access it using a key, it is undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access the dictionary in the "workload" in my document in firestore, however I am having difficulties trying to do so. This is my code:

```
async addTask() {
    const projectDoc = await getDoc(doc(db, "projects", "TestingNewNew"))
    const projectData = projectDoc.data();
    const employeeWorkload = projectData.workload
    console.log(employeeWorkload)
    console.log(employeeWorkload["Jimmy"])
}
```

When I console.log() the entire dictionary, I get the correct output, however when I try to access the dictionary through a particular, my console.log() reads undefined.

[image: console]

This is how my document in firestore looks

[image: Firestore document]

I tried many differents ways. I tried using the JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) method, but it still doesn't work. Please advice me on how I can approach the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Google APIs often make use of computed getters on objects and classes. These getters can lose their context (`this`) when reassigned to different variables.

This is what you're doing here:

```js
const employeeWorkload = projectData.workload
```

You should be able to see the correct output if you do this:

```js
console.log(projectData.workload.Jimmy)
```